# Texture cache overflow: 16 > texture units available

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, textures

I am creating an HTML5 web adventure game. I added some animated water to my [Tiled](https://www.mapeditor.org/) tilemap and am getting error:

> Class {name: "me.video.Error", message: "Texture cache overflow: 16
>   texture units available."}

I am conscious of rendering issues and packed my assets using [Texture Packer](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker), yet the problem intermittently appears.

[WebGL Stats](https://webglstats.com/webgl/parameter/MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS) shows the limit is 16 for ~70% of devices.

**My question(s)**: how can I find which textures are causing the issue? And why does it happen intermittently?

Comment: What engine are you using? That message is not from WebGL or the browser

Comment: Sounds like a MelonJS type error